# How can I pre-toggle a button in Bootstrap's btn-group?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I deploy the Radio Button group and make one of the buttons pre-toggled?

I have a radio-buttons group with days of the weeks values. This one:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button class="btn" id="test0">Mon</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test1">Tue</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test2">Wed</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test3">Thu</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test4">Fri</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test5">Sat</button>
  <button class="btn" id="test6">Sun</button>
</div>
```

What I need is to fetch the current day value (using `var currentDay = new Date().getDay()`) and `toggle` (activate) the corresponding button in the group.

And I'm trying to toggle it with the next code (just in testing purposes):

```
$("#test0").button('toggle')
```

This is not working.

Comment: By toggled do you mean active? As in, pressed?

Comment: Yes, toggled, active, pressed — it's all the same basically.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can take advantage of the bootstraps `.btn.active` class and just add it to the button you wish toggled first and you can use jQuerys [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to untoggle the buttons. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwMLt/).

---

Just noticed that twitter has a button script that you can call for this effect, here is a fixed [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwMLt/1/) with the results you were expecting.

---

After looking at what you actually wanted from the comment i updated my fiddle with the results you're looking for.

I added a function that pulls the current day using javascripts `getDay` method from an array and toggles the corresponding day on the button group by targetting the id of the button: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/ejW3w/)

Relevant Code:

**JS**

```
function today() {
    var arr = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]; //first day of the week is sunday and its index is 0
    var currentDay = new Date().getDay();

    return (arr[currentDay]);
}

var day = '[id="test' + today() +'"]'; // we take the current day from the array and add the beginning of the class name and save it in a variable

$(day).button('toggle');
```

Comment: Well. That's tricky. What I need exactly — I need to get the value of currewnt day (Mon, Tue, Wedn etc) and toggle the day which is now. So first I'll use newDate().getDay() and then according to the day I have I need to toggle the correct button. Could you advise me anything on this? Thanks

Comment: The easiest solution for me would be to make each button have a special "id", and then using that id toggle the correct one. But I don't understand the principles of the $("") syntax. I thought $("#id") would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @momijigari this is a totally different question then what is above :D ..update your question with everything you have written in the comment and a better explanation to see what we can do.

Comment: Updated :) Yeah, it was too abstract in the first edition of my question.

Comment: Yes, it's working now for me tahnks! (Forgot to put it all inside tha onLoad trigger)

Comment: I just wonder how come Bootstrap creators never mentioned anywhere in the documentation (if you can call it documentation after all) that you should use this weird syntax $('[id="blahblah"]')

Comment: @momijigari Because that is jQuery's syntax. Twitters Bootstrap uses jQuery plugins to function, and thus its syntax.

Comment: @momijigari to expand on Andres' comment about jQuery, you should rather be saying `$("#blahblah")` instead of `$("[id='blahblah']")`, it boils down to the same thing, but is more succinct. P.S. jQuery is awesome :) Also, I think for people that support non-JS browsers, you'd have to render it with the correct class (instead of relying purely on JS to toggle the class). Most people are lazy and just use JS to do it, which breaks if you can't run JS :)

Comment: The Demo above is no longer working, the bootstrap cdn stuff has moved.

Answer (score 28):

I tried the above but wanted a HTML/CSS solution only.

I found a *focus* based approach would work for Bootstrap 3. 
Note that ***autofocus*** is an **HTML5 attribute**.

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn" id="test0" autofocus="true">Mon</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test1">Tue</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test2">Wed</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test3">Thu</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test4">Fri</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test5">Sat</button>
      <button class="btn" id="test6">Sun</button>
</div>
```

I find [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com) is easier for fiddles with Bootstrap.
Here is my test bootply: **http://www.bootply.com/cSntVlPZtU**

Comment: A better answer for Bootstrap 3+. Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

just impersonate the button being click on page load:

$("#buttonid").trigger("click");

Worked for me for another similar standard button i wanted to show as having been clicked on page load - the button action was required to set the page default table view i wanted to display. Other buttons provide different views but the default one showed all data.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem but wanted a simpler solution. I've noticed that appending "active" to class doesn't solve the problem, as it is removed somehow (I haven't researched why it does this).

The solution is appending "active active" to class. This way, only one is removed and the other bypasses the magic that's happening behind. It's a really dirty solution, but it solves the problem. Hope it helps!