# How to activate bootstrap radio-style buttons via javascript?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Pretty simple thing I'm trying to do but I don't think bootstrap has a way to do this.

In my page I dynamically insert this bootstrap html using `innerHTML`:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

The html is not in the regular dom when the page loads, so the radio button behavior is not activated. How do I then activate the data-toggle="buttons-radio" via javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551628/how-can-i-pre-toggle-a-button-in-bootstraps-btn-group ??

Comment: Sorry this is not actually a duplicate

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do.. its already activated and you can click the buttons to toggle them..

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically insert`?

Comment: I feel there has to be a way to use the public api definitions in the plugin to activate these, but there's no clear documented way or even public method, I think there might be a certain argument to pass in but looking at the source that doesn't seem so.

Comment: Separate but related to my scenario, it seems between the jQuery, jQuery UI, and bootstrap versions being used in this project are all old and out of whack. I wish we had a special character for "developer sad face"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just call `button()` on the inserted button group? e.g. [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yStnW/), unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question, of course.

Comment: That didn't seem to work the first time so I threw my hands up. My real error was a version of jQuery that was a little to old.