# Pre-toggle a button in Bootstrap's btn-group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to set a selected button in Bootstrap's `btn-group`:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">7</button>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">8</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I pre-select option 5? [This answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551628/how-can-i-pre-toggle-a-button-in-bootstraps-btn-group) that I can add `active` class to the button, which does indeed work initially, but then clicking on the other buttons doesn't deactivate that button, as I would expect.

Here is a fiddle: http://bootply.com/90490

Here is another fiddle with the `active` class applied, showing why it isn't the correct solution: http://bootply.com/90491 - click on any of the other buttons, and button 5 still remains active.

Comment: Potential dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551628/how-can-i-pre-toggle-a-button-in-bootstraps-btn-group

Comment: Do you want there to be a single selection across multiple button groups or one selection per button group?

Comment: @JonathanBates I link to that question in my question, and explain why the accepted solution doesn't work for me. So not a dupe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that you want there to be a single selection per button group and that you have included the bootstrap JavaScript file, then the following should work.

#### Markup

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option5">5</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option6">6</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option7">7</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option8">8</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").first().button("toggle");
});
```

If you want to, for example, pre-toggle the third button, you can use the slice function like so:

```
$(".btn").slice(2,3).button("toggle");
```

Alternatively you could assign identifiers to the buttons.

Here's my fiddle: http://bootply.com/90501

Comment: Note: You can also use the `checked="checked"` attribute on whatever input you want selected by default. The wrapper label must also be tagged as `.active` so the CSS is correct.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for an answer to the pre-toggle a button and found this SO. They all seemed a bit difficult and I found a link to [BootStrap 4 checkbox buttons](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) which gave me some hints on how BootStrap 3 works. My solution is, I think, simpler as it can be pre-written in the html. The solution is below:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" checked>5
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio">6
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio">7
    </label>
</div>
```

As I say, this was prompted by BootStrap 4 docs but works on BootStrap 3. The important parts are:

1. The `data-toggle="buttons"` in the `btn-group` div.
2. The `active` class on the label 5.
3. The `checked` on the `<input type="radio">` for 5.

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove checked from input tag of first button,and add active class on condition .
eg:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{'active': splitOption=='equal'}" >
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"  > =
     </label>
</div>
```