# pre-pressed button in btn-group-justified doesn't want to return to normal state

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following justified buttons group using bootrap

```
    <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label" data-toggle="buttons">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">All</button>
             </div>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="audio" >Audiobooks</button>
             </div>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">E-books</button>
             </div>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">New</button>
             </div>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Premiers</button>
             </div>
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Super deals</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my jquery function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").first().button("toggle");
});
```

I used that solution from [Pre-toggle a button in Bootstrap's btn-group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633450/pre-toggle-a-button-in-bootstraps-btn-group) but it is not working well for me. When document is loaded, the button is in state - active, but it doesn't want to turn in normal state when the others buttons are clicked like on default without my jquery function.

Thanks for any answers and help

Comment: The example you quote is a bit different, they are using radio buttons, and the parent label has the btn class not the button itself. Would you like the first/active button to be disabled?

Comment: Hey do you want to show the first button as already pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if you want to show the first button is already pressed no need of jquery you can simply add a class active to the first element

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="label" data-toggle="buttons">
                 <button type="button" class="active btn btn-default btn-sm">All</button>
             </div>
```

Check below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/nak43d7x/

Comment: @depperm Yeah that is the next step of the answer dude

Comment: You guys should give +1 to answer also...:p ;)

Comment: That's not a correct answer. You are only preseting an initial CSS state, you aren't telling your button group "hey, you button, stay pressed initially".